# All Chrome browser windows go fullscreen for no reason on second monitor

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen

Anyone else experience this, have any idea how to prevent it from happening, or know what is causing it?

I roll with a bunch of Chrome browser windows open which have a varying number of active tabs. Some are fullscreen already, but most are on one of the desktops on a second monitor.

Every now and then when I click on a Chrome window all of the Chrome windows expand to fullscreen. Iirc, it is usually with an app switching click to Chrome on a browser window which is already fullscreen - then all the non-fullscreen windows expand.

specs: 15" 2017 MBP, 2.9GHz i7 16GB RAM, regular auto updates to OS and Chrome - currently maOS 10.14.2, Chrome 71.0.3578.98